# Cropping a Bitmap to an Area of Interest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, image-processing

Similar to my previous question which I as yet have not solved ([Comparing Frames of a live Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405830/comparing-frames-of-a-live-feed/24407343#24407343)) I have another issue.

**Scenario**

I have an image taken by a camera that contains a rectangle in it. I need to crop the image to only show the rectangle plus a small margin.

**My Efforts**

I have accomplished this by iterating through the pixels using LockBits and attempting to find potential edges but these seems terribly slow and inefficient

**My Thoughts**

I was thinking I could take an empty image as a baseline and then remove the differences between the two, however I cannot be sure that the lighting will be exactly the same and that potential contaminants such as an accidental fly getting into the image will not be present which could muck up this process.

Is there any easier way? The rectangle should (usually) be in the bottom left corner, but not always (long story) but this cant be relied upon.

**My Environment**

- Visual Studio 2012 (2010 if neccessary is available)
- Ueye camera
- C#
- The images are of type System.Drawing.Bitmap

The rectangle will often be something like a credit card or an ID card or anything of a similar size and shape

The empty image (background) looks like this:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crop image in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316941/crop-image-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Using EmguCV you can detect shapes such as a rectangle. Click [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp) for the emgu code. Once you have detected the rectangle it is fairly easy to crop it out using a new Bitmap with the size of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

The sample demonstrates how to crop the image from specific Picturebox control into destination Picturebox control using mouse selection or specified coordinates.

1.How to use mouse to select an area (rectangle) in a Picturebox control.

2.How to crop the image by the rectangle.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWinFormCropImage-d4beb1fa